# OnData event receives invalid Item.Index in WinXP

Tags: listview, delphi, windows-xp

I am using Delphi XE3 under WinXP.

In the following codes:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileName: string;
begin
  FFileList := TStringList.Create;

  for FileName in TDirectory.GetFiles(Edit1.Text) do
    FFileList.AddObject(FileName, nil);

  ListView1.Items.Count := FFileList.Count;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  //  The following error will never occur
  if Item.Index >= ListView1.Items.Count then
    Application.MessageBox('Invalid item index', 'Error');

  Item.Caption := 'TestCaption';
end;
```

I set ListView1.OwnerData to True, ListView1.OwnerDraw to False.

When running the codes under XP, in TForm1.ListView1Data, the app will pop up 'Invalid item index' error. Why?

**Update:**

I have uploaded the whole project source codes to https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsi7bh6xfkp6av3/Test4_1.zip?dl=0 , which can show the error under XP.

Comment: Works fine for me, with and without themes enabled. I've been using `TListView` in virtual mode for YEARS, including on XP, and have NEVER gotten a bad index from `Item.Index` in the `OnData` event. And I've NEVER had to resort to making sure manually that `Item.Index` is within the range of `TListView.Items.Count` - `TListView` already *guarantees* that internally before calling the `OnData` event handler.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I have uploaded the whole project source codes to https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsi7bh6xfkp6av3/Test4_1.zip?dl=0 , which can show the error under XP.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/34/292893.html) says that similar error arises when WinXP themes are loaded.

Seems that buggy library erroneously calculates position-index correspondence.

Workaround - just check for index validity

```
if (Item.Index > -1) and (Item.Index < ListView1.Items.Count) then
begin
...
end
```